# ActionMailer is working from console but not from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:forgotpassword][:email])
    Rails.logger.info "User: #{@user.inspect}"
    if @user
      @a=new_random_password
      @user.attributes={:temp_password=>@a}
      if @user.save(:validate=>false)
        byebug
        if Emailer.forgot_password_email(@user)
          flash[:success] = "Mail sent to #{params[:forgotpassword][:email]}"
          redirect_to fplast_path
        else
          flash[:error] = 'Email sending failed'
          redirect_to(:back)
        end
      else
        flash[:error] = 'Sorry!There is some problem. We can\'t process your email now.'
        redirect_to(:back)
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = 'This Email id is not registered. Please try with another or Sign up'
      redirect_to(:back)
    end
  end
```

This is my controller code which calls the following method to send emails.

```
#emailer.rb
class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from address", :charset => "UTF-8"

  def forgot_password_email(user)
    puts "HERE"
    Rails.logger.info "HERE"
    @user = user

    Rails.logger.info "Call came here at least"
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Reset password").deliver
  end
end
```

It seems the logs in the controller are getting printed but the logs in `emailer.rb` are not getting printed. From the rails console however, `Emailer.forgot_password_email` call prints logs and sends emails correctly. Please suggest.

Comment: remove `.deliver` from this line `mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Reset password")` and write it on `Emailer.forgot_password_email(@user).deliver` and try to send the mail.

Answer (score 1):

## controller

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:forgotpassword][:email])
    Rails.logger.info "User: #{@user.inspect}"
    if @user
      @a=new_random_password
      @user.attributes={:temp_password=>@a}
      if @user.save(:validate=>false)
        if Emailer.forgot_password_email(@user).deliver_now
          flash[:success] = "Mail sent to #{params[:forgotpassword][:email]}"
          redirect_to fplast_path
        else
          flash[:error] = 'Email sending failed'
          redirect_to(:back)
        end
      else
        flash[:error] = 'Sorry!There is some problem. We can\'t process your email now.'
        redirect_to(:back)
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = 'This Email id is not registered. Please try with another or Sign up'
      redirect_to(:back)
    end
  end
```

## emailer.rb

```
class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from address", :charset => "UTF-8"

  def forgot_password_email(user)
    puts "HERE"
    Rails.logger.info "HERE"
    @user = user

    Rails.logger.info "Call came here at least"
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Reset password")
  end
end
```

Comment: That works great. However, why was the emailer code not being accessed before.

Comment: It might be lazily executed? I'm having a similar issue and and still looking into it. I'll let you know when I find more.